# jQuery function for checking a check box checked and do an action for it

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want  to  write one  function in **jQuery**  that it can recognize  when user checked a check box  on my page then it know and  in real time (it means  when user checked check box  then label of  this `td` that `check-box` and  one `label`  are there **change color  to red**.

I  need  it because  I  have  one  `calendar`  that user  can  checked  `check box` of each day  for selecting holiday days of  one year  and then i  save all 365 days of  year  in my db  .
I  create a data-list and  Crete table  and  i have  365 `<td>` that  it contains  `< label >` and `< check box >`
`</td>`  for  each days of one year

I hope  help me  very soon thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and what specific point you're stuck on. Code is pretty much always required when asking a question here.

Comment: i have  no idea for  codeing  of  jquery  of this function i searched in google and  found i  can  use change()  for listing to  checkbox  but  i  dont know  corectly how?  <%--<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ForHolidayChanging").children("checkbox")(function () {
            $("CheckBox").change(function () {
         $("td").css({'background-color':'pink'});
    });});

});

</script>--%>

Comment: Then I would suggest hiring someone to help you. Stackoverflow is used to help people when they get stuck, not provide a work-for-free service.

Comment: no  i dont want free i get stuck  just i  want to know  how  can i  do  this  is it true  function that i  write above  just  help to find  a  good way for implementing

Answer (score 1):

dear try to use the following code

```
$(function() {
   $('#CheckBox').click(function () {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('Lable').css('background-color' , 'red');
       }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#checkbox').click(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $('#label').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

}

get this code in document ready function

Comment: i try this code but click is not in realtime i read about change method  and  i have to checked for 365 time becuse i have 365 day at one year and  for that reason i want to  use css class and  use it for my  data list then  i can  say if  one of checkbox that are in  this datalist  checked by user the lable of  it  change color to red   but thanks for  your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#checkboxid').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', 'Red');

});
```

or if you want to change the label color do this:

```
$('#checkboxid').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('td')find('td:first').css('background-color', 'Red');
});
```

write this in document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on

http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/4/

```
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="option-one" value="orange"><label for="option-one" class="highlight">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="option-two" value="apple"><label for="option-two" class="highlight">2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="option-three" value="apple"><label for="option-three" class="highlight">3</label>
</div>

.checkboxes label {
    font-family:Open Sans Italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: white;
    background: #86b3c1;
}
```

Are trying to achieve like this?